# How do I create an interactive photo gallery using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I'm trying to create an interactive photo gallery that displays thumbnails of images and on mouse-over enlarges them. 
I have created the following code, however, when I move the mouse over each photo, it has no effect.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> Photo Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<script>
var photos  = [];

photos.push({ image: "harrypotter.jpg", title: "Harry Potter" });
photos.push({ image: "lordoftherings.jpg", title: "Lord of the Rings" });
photos.push({ image: "backtothefuture.jpg", title: "Back To The Future" });


function changeImage(name)
{
  var photo;
  switch(name) {
    case "harrypotter":
        photo = photos[0];
    break;

    case "lordoftherings":
        photo = photos[1];
    break;

    case "backtothefuture":
        photo = photos[2];
    break;
  }

  var photogallery = document.getElementById("photogallery");
  var image = photogallery.getElementsByTagName("image");
  var title = photogallery.getElementsByTagName("h3");
  image[0].src = photo.image;
  title[0].innerHTML = photo.title;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "main">
 <h2> <u> Photo Gallery </u> </h2>
 <p> The following photos are the DVD covers of my favourite film. </p>


<div id="thumbnails">
    <img src="harry potter.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('harry potter')" alt = "Harry Potter Film Cover" width="110px" height="110px" />
    <img src="lordoftherings.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('lordoftherings')" alt = "Lord of the Rings Film Cover" width="110px" height="110px" />
    <img src="backtothefuture.jpg"        
onmouseover="changeImage('backtothefuture')" alt = "Back To The Future Film Cover" width="110px" height="110px" />
</div>
<div id="photogallery">
    <img src="harrypotter.jpg" alt="Harry Potter Film Cover" /><br />
<h3><em>Harry Potter</em></h3>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Change following line

```
var image = photogallery.getElementsByTagName("image");
```

to

```
var image = photogallery.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

secondly change `"changeImage('harry potter')"` to `"changeImage('harrypotter')"` as you are matching with space. I have tested it by creating a page and running it on firefox. [check this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/S0haib/zxha97zx/)
Images are coming from net in this fiddle so may be slow in loading.